# Como usar MBDootstrap Angular Scroll animation?

Tags: angular, animación

Estado realizando prácticas con `MDBootstrap` para `angular`. (Instalado desde `npm`).

En su documentación tienen tutoriales de como utilizar las animaciones de `css`.

Probe las animaciones y todo bien, el problema es cuando trato de implementar las animaciones con Scroll, la cual debes utilizar la clase `.wow` y agregar el script correspondiente (El cual no se si estoy agregando realmente el adecuado), alguien sabe como implementarlo?

Ejemplo: En mi app.component tengo un `<h1>` con la clase `wow` y el efecto de animacion `fadeInUp`

```
> <h1 class="py-5 font-weight-bold wow fadeInUp">Why is it so great?</h1>
```

luego en mi index.html , antes de del cierre de la etiqueta `</body>` tengo el script:

```
<script>
wow = new WOW({
    boxClass: 'wow', // default
    animateClass: 'animated', // default
    offset: 0, // default
    mobile: true, // default
    live: true // default
})
wow.init();
</scritp>
```

Comment: Bienvenido para que tu pregunta sea bien recibida por la comunidad te **invito a leer [ask]**

Comment: Bienvenido, podrías indicar que código has probado hasta ahora, donde te está dando algún problema etc así podrán ayudarte antes. Sería bueno que hicieras el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour), leyeras Cómo preguntar y editar así tu pregunta.